# Why NoSuchMethodError in ant built jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I'm trying to make an Ant build script for my project, which runs fine in Eclipse. When I try to run the exported jar:

```
java -verbose:class -jar MyProject.jar
```

I get an unexpected error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.employer.MyInterface.myMethod()I
```

what's really weird about this is debugging attempts like these all appear to be producing expected output (both before the export and after):

```
System.out.println("1:" + (myObj instanceof MyClass));
System.out.println("2:" + (myObj instanceof MyInterface));
Class c = MyClass.class;
URL myClassURL = c.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
        .getLocation();
System.out.println("url: " + myClassURL);
try {
   Method[] m = c.getDeclaredMethods();
   for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(m[i].toString());
   }
} catch (Throwable e) {
   System.err.println(e);
}
System.out.println("gni2:" + myObj.myMethod());
```

where `MyClass` implements `MyInterface`. That is, I can see both the interface and the class in my jar file if I examine it using emacs, I see the class loader load each of them, I see `myMethod` in `getDeclaredMethods`, there's only one `MyClass.class` in the jar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed this to an Answer your own question because I figured it out while typing up the question. Instead of deleting the question, here's the solution just in case it helps someone else.

The problem ended up being that 2 of the projects that my project depends on have overlapping package+class names. I think a colleague copied code from one project to the other at some point in the past and then only maintained one of them. Eclipse uses the first class it finds based the order in a Build Path setting, whereas Ant overwrites one class with the other based on the order in the build file (and the orders end up being reversed).